# Fluent NHibernate Many-To-Many relationship over non-indexed database view

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a database view that joins on a number of tables to select visibility of a number of entities against member ids, which due to its complexity is obviously non-indexable. So what I need is to be able to select from those entities against the member Id. I tried this with a many-to-many relationship using a collection with the view as the mapping table:

```
    public PromotionMap()
    {
        ...

        this.HasManyToMany(p =>  p.MembersCanView).Table("PromotionVisibility").Not.Cascade.SaveUpdate().ParentKeyColumn("PromotionId").ChildKeyColumn("MemberId").ReadOnly();
    }
```

Though this seems like it should work, the behaviour is not read only and the session always tries to flush changes back to the database view, which obviously fails. This is especially problematic because there's a good chance that the view will change as a result of an insert or delete operation.

Section 10.2.3.3 here: http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#readonly-proptypes-manytomany-bidir suggests that a bidirectional many-to-many relationship will always flush no matter what, so that leaves me a bit stuck for how I can query entities by joining on the view.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.Not` affects only boolean properties like *Readonly*, *LazyLoad* and not multiple choices like *Cascade*. Therefor your code specified `.Not.Readonly()`

```
HasManyToMany(p =>  p.MembersCanView)
    .Table("PromotionVisibility")
    .Cascade.None()                      <-- None instead of .Not
    .ParentKeyColumn("PromotionId")
    .ChildKeyColumn("MemberId")
    .ReadOnly();
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have done the trick. I found that it was still trying to cascade delete, but I was able to stop that by also inversing the relationship.